# Reading SIP invite packets before reaching softphone

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, udp, sip

I'm trying to create an wpf-app that read/sniff the SIP-invite (UDP) for every incoming call to my softphone. Problem is that I can't connect to the same port. I tried to run it in administrator mode as well.

An exception is thrown:

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Here's the code:

```
readonly Thread _thread;
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _thread = new Thread(ReceiveMessage) {IsBackground = true};
        _thread.Start();
    }

private void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        var udpClient = new UdpClient();
        var remoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 59724);
        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        udpClient.Client.Bind(remoteIpEndPoint);
        while (true)
        {

            var content = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteIpEndPoint);

            if (content.Length > 0)
            {
                var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(content);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The message is clear the port you try to register (59724) is already in use by other application that can't share it, it doesn't matter if you run the application with Admin privileges or not. It could be easier if you make a proxy for the SIP server so your SIP client connects to it, but i'm not a SIP expert so I can't tell it will work.

Comment: Ok, I dont have any control over the SIP server, I only got the softphone credentials. Is there any way of sniff for udp packets like wireshark without blocking the socket?

Comment: You can sniff packets reaching your computer but, if I understand properly, what you want to achieve is some kind of man-in-the-middle scenario, am I wrong?